# Tell which direction one is going (left/right) given 2 coordinates

Tags: java, graph, coordinates

If you had a coordinate system or map (or a 2D array if you will) and each cell was numbered from [0,0] to [m,n]. **How would it be possible to tell which direction one was going each step** given a start and a destination coordinate? One can go 8 directions if not at border of the grid (North, South, North-West etc.). So there is no going up or down just left/right etc.

The goal is to have a sequence of "Go right", "Go half-left", ... up to the destination **considering which direction one is looking at all times.** For example if one is looking to left side of the map and moving forward one will land in the same cell as someone who is looking up the grid but going left.

**Example**

From [0,0] to [2,1]. For illustration reasons I drew 2 steps (or three steps if you count the step into the grid). Each arrow also tells from which direction one entered the cell also the direction one looks after entering. For example in cell [1,1] one looks North-East.

[image]

I hope this is not too off-topic, but in my opinion it is a programming problem. How you answer is up to you. I implemented this as a graph in Java

Comment: Are you asking this for a single step, and do you want diagonals included?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by diagonals included, but I clarified a little bit in my topic. I want in each cell of the way a command. For example when one is standing in cell [0,0] the next command should be "Go half-right" or "North-East"

Comment: Not sure that I understand your quetion correctly but if X in the to-coordinate is lower than X in the from-coordinate, you're going left and vice versa.

Comment: You are right but this only applies if you're looking up the grid. If you are already looking to the left side of the grid you are going forward in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing to do is to add the "current direction" to the state of the Hobo. I'll use an enum N, NE, E,... for the state and for the direction of the move. Then the "direction" can be computed from a table; I use A(head) H(alf)L(eft), L(eft)

```
          Hobo faces
        N  NE  E  ...
    ------------------
Dir N | A  HL  L  ...
    NE| HR A   HL ...
    E | R  HR  A  ...
    ...
```

**Implementation suggested by TomTom**

The keys in this HashMap are "LOOKING_DIRECTION" + "GLOBAL_MOVE_DIRECTION" tuples and the values you get are a left/right/.. in form of west/east/.. (these directions are not globally but subjective) and at the same time the looking direction for the next step.

```
HashMap<String, String> DIR_CONVERTER = new HashMap<>();

String[] directions = {"N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"};

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        DIR_CONVERTER.put(directions[i]+directions[j], directions[(j+8-i)%8]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought there was an "easy" and clever algorithmic way to solve this problem, but lookup table seems to be the easier way (maybe even the only). Thanks!

Comment: @TomTom You can come up with a function that does the same, but I do like tables. You can always improve on the implementation technique later.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added my implementation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you implement your move algorithm, for example  you could move east, then  north east, and end up in the same spot, the order of the directed is commutative.

however, when you actually go to code it, you can make sure you always go through the list of directions in a certain order, for example in the pseudo code here:

```
while(!atDesintaion): //every iteration is a step
    //work out direction from with reference to the background
    direction = "";
    if(destinationY >currentY) {
        currentY++; //move north
        direction = "North";
    }
    else {
        currentY--; //move south
        direction = "North";
    }
    if(destinationX >currentX) {
        currentX++; //move east
        direction += "East";
    }
    else {
        currentX--; //move west
        direction += "West";
    }

    rotation = "North";
    if(currentAngle >= 0 && currentAngle < 22.5 || currentAngle >= 337.5 && currentAngle <= 360) rotation = "North";
    else if(currentAngle >= 22.5 && currentAngle < 77.5) rotation = "NorthEast";
    else if(currentAngle >= 77.5 && currentAngle < 112.5) rotation = "East";
    etc...
    else if(currentAngle >= 292.5 && currentAngle < 337.5) rotation = "NorthWest";

   if(rotation != "North") {
       switch(rotation) {
           case NorthEast: 
               switch(direction) {
                   case North: direction = "NorthEast";
                   case NorthEast: direction = "East";
                   etc...
               }
           case East: 
               switch(direction) {
                   case North: direction = "East";
                   case NorthEast: direction = "SouthEast";
                   etc...
               }
           etc...
       }
   }
}
```

If you ran through any starting co-ordinate and any destination co-ordinate, it will move diagonally first until it can't then in a one of the 4 remaining directions until it reaches the target, so each step can keep track of which direction it just moved

EDIT: @laune's lookup table is much simpler than anything I was trying, go with that for the rotations update

Comment: The problem I had is that you are not always facing north. So north is subjective in my problem. If you are looking down the grid then north would be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Table of directions

```
x+, y=     right
x-, y=     left
x=, y+     up
x=, y-     down
x+, y+     up-right
x+, y-     down-right
x-, y+     up-left
x-, y-     down-left
```

You could use an if statement of some sort to figure out which way to move

```
if (userinput == up) {
    y++;
}
```

or if are just trying to figure out how it moved, use spyr's suggestion.

Comment: You are not taking into account which direction one looks in each cell. x+, y= is only going right if you look upwards on the grid (I clarified a little in my post)